# Apostrophe CKEditor table cell merging issue

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, apostrophe-cms

In apostrophe-rich-text widget when I paste a table (but it also happens when creating them manually) with merged cells it starts out fine:

[image: Freshly pasted table]

But after a reload, colspans disappear:

[image]

Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try whitelisting the `colspan` attribute in your project level `apostrophe-rich-text-widgets` `index.js`

```
module.exports = {
  sanitizeHtml: {
    allowedAttributes: {
      'td': ['colspan']
    }
  }
};
```